# Prevent blank sheets with Laravel Excel

Tags: excel, laravel

I'm implementing Excel download on my app using Laravel Excel. It works well except that it creates an empty sheet if the query finds no data.  Is there any way to prevent this?

This is the code for the sheets:

```
namespace App\Exports\Sheets;

use App\Models\WebArchiveTest;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class WebArchiveSheet implements FromQuery, WithTitle
{
    protected string $category;
    protected string $server;

    public function __construct(string $server, string $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function query(): Builder
    {
        return WebArchiveTest
            ::query()
            ->select(['web_root', 'page_title'])
            ->where('server', $this->server)
            ->where('category', $this->category);
    }

    public function title(): string
    {
        return ucfirst($this->category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if there actually _is_ data before outputting it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to check whether the query result is empty or not before generating the Excel worksheet. If the query result contains data (is not empty), then the Excel worksheet will contain that data. However, if the query result is empty, then the code ensures that the Excel worksheet is not created, so you won't receive an empty worksheet in the export result.

```html
namespace App\Exports\Sheets;

use App\Models\WebArchiveTest;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class WebArchiveSheet implements FromQuery, WithTitle
{
    use Exportable;

    protected string $category;
    protected string $server;

    public function __construct(string $server, string $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function query(): Builder
    {
        $query = WebArchiveTest::query()
            ->select(['web_root', 'page_title'])
            ->where('server', $this->server)
            ->where('category', $this->category);

        // Check if the query has any results, if not, return an empty result set
        if (!$query->exists()) {
            $query->whereRaw('1 = 0'); // This will ensure the query returns an empty result set
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function title(): string
    {
        return ucfirst($this->category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  I tried this and, unfortunately, it still gave me blank sheets.  My eventual solution is below.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Adam Faturahman, I refactored both the Export and Sheet code as follows:

Export:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Exports\Sheets\WebArchiveSheet;
use App\Models\WebArchiveTest;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class WebArchiveExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    use Exportable;

    protected string $server;

    public function __construct(string $server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];

        $this->getCategories()
            ->each(function ($result) use (&$sheets) {
                $query = $this->getSheetData($result->category);
                if (! $query) {
                    return;
                }
                $sheet = new WebArchiveSheet($query, $result->category);
                $sheets[] = $sheet;
            });

        return $sheets;
    }

    protected function getCategories(): Builder
    {
        return WebArchiveTest::query()
            ->select(['category'])
            ->where('server', $this->server)
            ->orderBy('category')
            ->distinct();
    }

    protected function getSheetData(string $category): ?Builder
    {
        $query = WebArchiveTest
            ::query()
            ->select(['web_root', 'page_title'])
            ->where('server', $this->server)
            ->where('category', $category);

        return $query->exists() ? $query :null;
    }
}
```

Sheet:

```
namespace App\Exports\Sheets;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class WebArchiveSheet implements FromQuery, WithTitle
{
    protected Builder $query;
    protected string $category;

    public function __construct(Builder $query, string $category)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
        $this->category = $category;
    }
    
    public function query(): Builder
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function title(): string
    {
        return ucfirst($this->category);
    }
}
```